# Установил python в директорию без русских букв,ошибка с pyinstaller осталась

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Раньше была ошибка,в ответах автор вопроса написал что установил python в директорию без русских букв и всё заработало,я сделал также,но ошибка осталась:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'd:\pythoninstalling\python.exe' 'd:\pythoninstalling\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\4D2B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpehob5vkp'
     cwd: C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-km5oss6h\pyinstaller
Complete output (38 lines):
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info
writing C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\pythoninstalling\python.exe' 'd:\pythoninstalling\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\4D2B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpehob5vkp' Check the logs for full command output.

Установил на диск D. Путь выглядит так: "D:\PythonInstalling"
Что делать?

Comment: А это `creating C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-5ddfz92m\pyinstaller.egg-info`?

Comment: Как изменить этот путь?

Comment: Вы через `pip` пробовали? Я только что установил `pyinstaller`, хотя Python находится в `C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`

Comment: через pip и устанавливал

Comment: pip install pyinstaller